# NPM fails when installing image-webpack-loader. I can't proceed with my project.

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install

Webpack was working fine all day and when I added a new image it suddenly failed. I updated node and npm and I still get the following error. How would I go about fixing this or using an alternative? The other image loader modules I attempted to install give the same error.

```
74857 verbose stack Error: gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
74857 verbose stack Exit status 1
74857 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mykod\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
74857 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
74857 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
74857 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mykod\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
74857 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
74857 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
74857 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
74857 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
74858 verbose pkgid gifsicle@3.0.4
74859 verbose cwd C:\Users\mykod\Desktop\best-voted
74860 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
74861 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mykod\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
74862 error node v6.9.4
74863 error npm  v4.3.0
74864 error code ELIFECYCLE
74865 error errno 1
74866 error gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
74866 error Exit status 1
74867 error Failed at the gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall script 'node lib/install.js'.
74867 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
74867 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the gifsicle package,
74867 error not with npm itself.
74867 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
74867 error     node lib/install.js
74867 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
74867 error     npm bugs gifsicle
74867 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
74867 error     npm owner ls gifsicle
74867 error There is likely additional logging output above.
74868 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Restarting doesn't help for me. There was problems with permissions on my laptop.
I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is solution: [fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

I'm recommending to watch video first.
At least check NPM's directory first `npm config get prefix` and if it's **/usr**, you have to use **Option 2**.

I've solved this problems with processing step by step of **Option 2**.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my computer and was able to install it. Windows.